# How to get random numbers from /color/random API?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a random color picker in React. For this purpose I am trying to use the following API:

```
https://www.colr.org/json/color/random
```

It seems to be working in a browser (giving different numbers after page reload), but I have been unable to get more than one number, over and over again, with my GET requests...

```
function App() {
  const [color, colorSet] = useState("");
  const url = "https://www.colr.org/json/color/random";

  useEffect(() => {}, [color]);

  const getEm = () => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((rez) => {
        console.log(rez);
        colorSet(rez.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  console.log(color);
```

The button is here:

```
<Button style={{ background: `#` + `${color}` }} onClick={() => getEm()}>
        color
      </Button>
```

Did anyone else ran into a similar issue?

Comment: Please explain your use case. Do u want to change the color without refresh the page ?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the color of the button when it's clicked!

Comment: No error, just the same hex over and over again...

Answer (score 1):

Success!

```
  const url = `https://www.colr.org/json/color/random?query&timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`;
```